# C# Single Thread Code Breaker Not Working

Tags: c#, single-threaded

I am new to programming in C#, I have been following Ringlers Complete Guide to C# as I need to demonstrate a simple code breaker, locking up the UI due to it only being single threaded when any other button is clicked. I have followed the tutorial in the book, but when I click start it just inputs the code and the UI is fully working. Can anyone tell me what is missing in the code? Thank you

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    // The simulated code to be broken
    private string Code;
    // The list of Labels of the characters to be broken.
    private List<TextBlock> OutputCharLabels;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Generating a random code to be broken 
        SimulateCodeGeneration();
        // Create a new list of Label controls that show the characters of the code being broken.        
        OutputCharLabels = new List<TextBlock>(4);
        // Add the Label controls to the List        
        OutputCharLabels.Add(txtOutput1);
        OutputCharLabels.Add(txtOutput2);
        OutputCharLabels.Add(txtOutput3);
        OutputCharLabels.Add(txtOutput4);

        //Hide the Stop button initially.
        btnStop.IsEnabled = false;

        // Hide the demo form and show the CodeBreaker 
        showCodeBreaker(); 
    }
    private void SimulateCodeGeneration()
    {
        // A Random number generator.    
        Random loRandom = new Random();
        // The char position being generated    
        int i;
        Code = "";
        for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            // Generate a Random Unicode char for each of the 4 positions                  
            Code += (char)(loRandom.Next(65535));
        }
    }
    private void setDemoVisibility(System.Windows.Visibility pbValue)
    {
        // Change the visibility of the controls related to the demo game.  
        btnGameOver.Visibility = pbValue;
    }

    private void setCodeBreakerVisibility(System.Windows.Visibility pbValue)
    {
        // Change the visibility of the controls related to the CodeBreaking procedure.  
        txtCodeBreaker.Visibility = pbValue;
        txtNumber1.Visibility = pbValue;
        txtNumber2.Visibility = pbValue;
        txtNumber3.Visibility = pbValue;
        txtNumber4.Visibility = pbValue;
        txtOutput1.Visibility = pbValue;
        txtOutput2.Visibility = pbValue;
        txtOutput3.Visibility = pbValue;
        txtOutput4.Visibility = pbValue;
        btnStart.Visibility = pbValue;
        btnHide.Visibility = pbValue;
        btnStop.Visibility = pbValue;
    }
    private void showDemo()
    { // Hide all the controls related to the code
      // breaking procedure.
        setCodeBreakerVisibility(System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden);
        // Change the window title 
        this.Title = "Demo Form";
        // Make the Demo form visable 
        setDemoVisibility(System.Windows.Visibility.Visible);
    }
    private void showCodeBreaker()
    {
        // Hide all the controls related to Demo form
        setDemoVisibility(System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden);
        // Change the window title   
        this.Title = "CodeBreaker Application";
        // Make the code breaker controls visible 
        setCodeBreakerVisibility(System.Windows.Visibility.Visible);
    }
    private bool checkCodeChar(char pcChar, int piCharNumber)
    {
        // Returns a bool value indicating whether the piCharNumber position of the code is the pcChar received.       
        return (Code[piCharNumber] == pcChar);

    }

    private void btnGameOver_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Hide the CodeBreaker and show the demo form   
        showDemo(); 
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This code will break the simulated code.
        // This variable will hold a number to iterate from 1 to 65,535 - Unicode character set.      
        int i;
        // This variable will hold a number to iterate from 0 to 3 (the characters positions in the code to be broken).   
        int liCharNumber;
        // This variable will hold a char generated from the number in i      
        char lcChar;
        // This variable will hold the current Label control that shows the char position being decoded.       
        TextBlock loOutputCharCurrentLabel;
        for (liCharNumber = 0; liCharNumber < 4; liCharNumber++)
        {
            loOutputCharCurrentLabel = OutputCharLabels[liCharNumber];

            // This loop will run 65,536 times        
            for (i = 0; i <= 65535; i++)
            {
                // myChar holds a Unicode char        
                lcChar = (char)(i);
                loOutputCharCurrentLabel.Text = lcChar.ToString();
                if (checkCodeChar(lcChar, liCharNumber))
                {
                    // The code position was found        
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }`
```

Comment: what happens when you debug your code and trace through your start button code?

Comment: As soon as `checkCodeChar()` returns true, the inner loop breaks. It's almost certainly not iterating 64K times (despite the comment), and I bet the entire method returns so quickly you're not seeing the UI locking up. Replace the whole button handler code with `Thread.Sleep(10000);` and you'll see it locking up!

Comment: Really appreciate the reply, that is exactly whats happening, its returning so quickly that I am unable to demonstrate it locking up. I need to be able to start the code breaking, then lock the program up by hitting the hide button, so I am unable to replace the whole button handler?